# Django Makemigrations No changed detected

Tags: python, django, django-models

app/models:

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class Blogpost(models.Model):
    topic = models.TextField(null=True)
    descrip = models.TextField()
    fd = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

---

->I installed app already

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'website.apps.SbuiltConfig',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

---

->I Register models already

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Blogpost, Blog, testblog
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Blogpost)
```

but it's still no change detected
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noow7.png)

Comment: Can you share the relative path of each file?

Comment: if your folder name where your ```Blogpost``` model is ```app```, then you have to mention ```app``` in settings.py under ```INSTALLED_APPS```.

Comment: @ybl I edited my question you can see my all path in the image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should mention your app/folder name in the INSTALLED_APPS list.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'website.apps.SbuiltConfig',
    'rest_framework',
     
     # If your app's root folder name is Blogpost
    'Blogpost',

     # Or if your app's folder name is website
     'website',
]
```

then after saving your settings.py, in terminal/shell:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

you can also mention your app's name explicitly in command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations Blogpost
python manage.py migrate
```

if your app's name is website then:

```
python manage.py makemigrations website
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: my app's name is website. but python manage.py makemigrations website
got -> No installed app with label 'website'.           but I mentioned already

Comment: have you tried just adding 'website' instead of 'website.apps.SbuiltConfig'? and are you aware of the path you're executing the makemigrations command?